# c++ reference to upper level stack variable

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

In the following code, the `getElement` function offers several ways to return the value of the element of a vector allocated on the caller stack.

NB. I know one could just use `v[1]` in `main` to achieve the same result, but this is for illustration purposes.

- Which of the 4 methods allows to get a valid 'handle' on the vector element after `getElement` has returned?
- Would the use of `std::move` be justified here?
- What would be the best way to go?

Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Foo {...};

void getElement(int idx,
                vector<Foo> vValue, vector<Foo>& vRef,
                Foo& fooRef, Foo* fooPtr)
{
    // (vector size checks ommitted for clarity)

    // Which of the (exclusive) following instructions allows to
    // correctly handle the vector element from the main function?
    fooRef = vValue[idx]; //method 1: by reference on a vector copy
    &fooPtr = vValue[idx]; //method 2: by pointer on a vector copy
    fooRef = vRef[idx]; //method 3: by reference on a vector reference
    &fooPtr = vRef[idx]; //method 4: by pointer on a vector reference
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    vector<Foo> v { Foo(..), Foo(..), Foo(..) };
    Foo fooVal(..);
    getElement(1, v, v, fooVal, &fooVal);

    // Use fooVal here to handle the vector element
}
```

Comment: In turn: 3 or 4, no, 3.

Comment: 2 and 4 don't modify the `fooPtr` in `main`.

Comment: arf, I wrote the snippet too quickly, just corrected it.